# OmegaFromSem function in the 'psych' package reads a wrong G factor. Any ideas?

Tags: r, factor-analysis, lavaan

I have fitted a confirmatory bifactor model in lavaan. I then use the omegafromSEM function in the 'psych' package to read the lavaan object and get the omega coefficients. However, the omegafromSem function confuses a group factor with the g factor. The results looks like this: [image]

Any ideas for correcting this?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Answer: Psych package reads the first factor that is specified in the lavaan syntax as the G factor. When the problem appeared, I had first specified the group factor that psych was confusing with the G factor. I flipped their positions. It now works :D